# escape characters in variables in a batch script

Tags: variables, batch-file, escaping

I have i.a. variables like:

```
SET CURRHOST=myServer
SET CURRCOMPANY=myCompany
SET CURRDB=string!string=string!string=string
```

after I set this variable:

```
SET NAME=%CURRHOST%\%CURRCOMPANY%\%CURRDB%
```

I also used the variables above in other variables. But my problem is now, that the script thinks that my CURRDB variable is a command.

I tried to escape the variable like

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET CURRDB=string^^!string^^=string^^!string^^=string
```

and then use this variable in other variables with

```
!CURRDB!
```

But it does not work. It also removes the ! character and the string between the = character.

So how can I escape this characters in the CURRDB variable.

EDIT:

what I am trying to do exaktly:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set CURRHOST=myServer
set CURRCOMPANY=myCompany
set CURRDBASE=string!string=string!string=string
set CURRSQLCMD="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn"
set CURRFILETREE=E:\SWF_DBankBackup\MSSQL2012
```

After I use these variables obove for other variables:

```
set DateiName=%CURRHOST%_%CURRDBASE%_BackupCurrent
set Backuppath=%CURRFILETREE%\%CURRCOMPANY%\%CURRDBASE%
set BackupSkript=%Backuppath%\BackupCurrentScript\%DateiName%_Full_Script.sql
set BackupBAKpath=%Backuppath%\Current
set BackupTXTpath=%Backuppath%\Current\txt
```

But the Problem is the variable CURRDB. The script handles it as a command because of the characters ! and = in the string. So I get an error that in cmd `'testtest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable programm or batch file.` So it seems like that the script removes the `!` and the `=` from the variable.

So how can I escape the `!` and the `=` in the variable?

Comment: Do not use spaces around the `SET` command. Use `SET CURRDB=string...`, else you got variable names with a space like `CURRDB<space>`

Comment: Remove the SPACEs around the `=`; otherwise it becomes part of the variable name and the string value...

Comment: I don't have spaces in my script. I just used it here for clrearness.

Comment: 1. please show us what exactly you want the variable to be expanded to; 2. I think you do not have to escape the `=`...

Comment: I edited my post. Have a look at it

Comment: @EmreBeloz, why do you need delayed expansion on at this point in your script? It never hurts to enclose your SET commands inside quotes.  I try to make it one of my best coding practices but do forget to do it from time to time. `set "CURRDBASE=string!string=string!string=string"`

Comment: Please show the line where CURRDB (or CURRDBASE?) fails with the error message. Btw. when delayed expansion is enabled then you need to escape the exclamation marks `set "CURRDBASE=string^!string=string^!string=string"`.  Where is `testest` come from? Is it a part of any directory? Do you have directories with ampersands `&` in the name? Please show the **relevant** part of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your escaping seems to work on my end. Could it be you're using the percent sign `%` for the constructed variable? Check this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET CURRHOST=myServer
SET CURRCOMPANY=myCompany
SET CURRDB=string^^!string=string^^!string=string

ECHO correct: %CURRHOST%\%CURRCOMPANY%\!CURRDB!
ECHO broken : %CURRHOST%\%CURRCOMPANY%\%CURRDB%

SET NAME=%CURRHOST%\%CURRCOMPANY%\!CURRDB!

ECHO correct: !NAME!
ECHO broken : %NAME%
```

Outputs:

```
correct: myServer\myCompany\string!string=string!string=string
broken : myServer\myCompany\stringstring=string
correct: myServer\myCompany\string!string=string!string=string
broken : myServer\myCompany\stringstring=string
```

The broken strings exactly match the misbehaviour you describe.

Delayed expansion isn't exactly easy to get your head around and the official documentation is mostly bad. [I'd recommend reading on SS64, here's their page on delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: @EmreBeloz: Did you run the above script and it produced a different output? I looked at your edit - you are indeed using percent signs `%`. As you can see from the above script, you need to use exclamation marks `!`.

Comment: @EmreBeloz: I've expanded the example above to show the problem you're witnessing more clearly.